# html entity names not being displayed as the relevant html symbol in jasper report

Tags: html, entity, jasper-reports

I've queries that retrieve snippets of text, which contain various html entity names, most notably `&euro;` and `&lambda;`, (not the actual symbol ie € or λ) from a database. I use the *same* queries to display reams of text in the browser, and in a RTF jasper report. the symbols are always displayed correctly in the browser.

However when i execute the query in jasper to generate a rtf doc, the `&euro;` string
comes out in the rtf doc as "&euro" ie the semi-colon has dissappeared, so instead of €1,000 I get &euro1000. Below is a textfield from my report. I've tried wrapping $P{label.htmlSnippet} in a CDATA but with no luck, the markup is html...so not sure what else I can do?

`<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="None">
  <reportElement positionType="Float" x="375" y="285" width="80" height="12"/>
  <textElement textAlignment="Right" markup="html"></textElement>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">$P{label.htmlSnippet}</textFieldExpression>
</textField>`

any help, ideas suggestions appreciated

regards
John

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745406/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-jasperreports

Answer (score 1):

For a `TextField` object you need to set its `markup` property to `html`. As you say, `&euro;` is a HTML entity, not a RTF special symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need isStyledText="true" in the textElement? I'm not sure; I use iReport and the only example I have involves a static text box (not a textField as you have). I have the isStyledText attribute.