# How to decode html entities in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, html-entities

I have some reports written in JasperReports and they display html entities literally, for example, bullet point • is shown using html entity textual representation: #8226;.

Do you know any way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `textField` set the `markup` attribute as `html`.

this is how to add in 5.6 version of iReport studio

`<textField ........>
    <reportElement ........./>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[..........]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>`

Comment: Hi Rogel garcia, I need to show ✔ mark in jrxml. For that i tried  "\u2714" and  "&#10004;" but not working. please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iReport for designing the reports, checkout "markup" property in the properties window, for that particular field.

Answer (score 0):

As the reports are XML layouts, they can be converted to UTF-8 easily as 8226 is the Unicode number.